# How to get redirected url in flutter which open app?

Tags: flutter, url, android-manifest, data-uri, app-launcher

I define host URL in my Flutter app

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="example.io" />
</intent-filter>
```

`example.io` is my base URL when I click any URL with this base it open my app how I can get

```
https://example.io/uniqueid
https://example.io/
```

When I tap on either above URL, it opens my app.  How I can get uniqueId every-time when app is launched with my URL?